# Python gspread информация списком из ячеек в сообщение телеграмм пользователю

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram-bot

Подскажите плз, столкнулся с проблемой: бот по запросу получает информацию из гугл таблиц и отправляет ее сообщением для пользователя, но в сообщении приходит только первая ячейка, а не весь столбец.

```py
val1 = ws.col_values(1)
bot.send_message(message.chat.id,(val1))
```

Если сделать проверку `print(val1)`, то вся информация из заполненных ячеек приходит как надо. Спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

.col_values() возвращает список, попробуйте или привести его к строке:

```
bot.send_message(message.chat.id, str(val1))
```

или

```
bot.send_message(message.chat.id, ' '.join(map(str, val1)))
```

Comment: Спасибо работают оба варианта.

Comment: Всегда пожалуйста 